# Android studio “ Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference”

Tags: android, android-dialog

I can't get past this “Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference” error.

So my `Button` on the code below opens a `CustomDialog` with an `EditText` where the user can update his email address.

```
        btnChangeEmail=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChangeEmail);
        btnChangeEmail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            //Change Email Dialog
            public void onClick (View arg0){
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.email_dialog);
                //dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        EditText txtNewEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNewEmail);
                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        alert.setTitle("Are you sure?");
                        alert.setMessage("Use " + txtNewEmail.getText().toString() + " as your new address?");
                        alert.setCancelable(false);
                        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });
                        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                });

                Button exitButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonExit);
                exitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
                Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                float h = (float) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * .9);
                float w = (float) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);
                int height = (int) h;
                int width = (int) w;
                window.setLayout(width, height);
            }
        }
```

By clicking the save button in the aforementioned custom dialog, it opens up an alert which prompts the user if he in fact wants to continue and overwrite his registered email address. I clearly instantiated the txtNewEmail but always get the null object reference error on the line where it says

alert.setMessage("Use " + txtNewEmail.getText().toString() + " as your new address?");

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my full logcat error...

```
03-05 01:51:57.704 4512-4512/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.twenty, PID: 4512
                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                 at com.example.twenty.SettingsActivity$4$1.onClick(SettingsActivity.java:193)
                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please add your full error that can be seen in the logcat.

Comment: You have a NullPointerException. Please note that `findViewById` will return null if the given id is not found in the layout you are searching

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to invoke virtual method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995264/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method)

Comment: I think your context is null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your edittext inside onClickListener will also be using dialog to find id like this

```
EditText txtNewEmail = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextNewEmail);
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you. This one really worked for me. I'll be more mindful of this issue next time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

remove and add initiated txtNewEmail outside of Listener

```
final EditText txtNewEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNewEmail);
btnChangeEmail=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChangeEmail);
```

Comment: I tried this earlier myself but it still gives the same error. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText txtNewEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNewEmail);
```

this object is null(txtNewEmail) call this method(findViewById) by the view father

**change**

```
  alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
```

**with**

```
  alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            alert.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your instructions at first but now I get them. Thank you.

Comment: father is the dialog

Comment: father is confusing you should use `parent` for that reference.